# How to get the last row value in a dataframe that fulfill a condition multiple times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe as follow:

| Index | Value | Condition1 | Condition2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True | False |
| 2 | 5 | False | False |
| 3 | 3 | False | True |
| 4 | 3 | False | False |
| 5 | 3 | True | False |
| 6 | 6 | False | True |

I wish to check when the row with condition 2 is true. Populate the new column with the last previous row with condition 1 to be true. Example of desired output:

| Index | Value | Condition1 | Condition2 | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True | False | None |
| 2 | 5 | False | False | None |
| 3 | 3 | False | True | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | False | False | None |
| 5 | 3 | True | False | None |
| 6 | 6 | False | True | 3 |

I tried using tail() with np.where():

```
df["New Column"] = np.where(df["Condition 2"]==True,df[df["Condition 1"]==True].["Value"].tail(1),None)
```

However, this gave a syntax error. Since the data frame size may get bigger, I hope to achieve this without using a loop method as well.

Appreciate any help and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use masks and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) combined with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['New Column'] = (df['Value'].where(df['Condition1']).ffill()
                    .where(df['Condition2'])
                   )
```

Variant with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['Condition2'], 'New Column'] = df['Value'].where(df['Condition1']).ffill()
```

Output:

```
   Index  Value  Condition1  Condition2  New Column
0      1      1        True       False         NaN
1      2      5       False       False         NaN
2      3      3       False        True         1.0
3      4      3       False       False         NaN
4      5      3        True       False         NaN
5      6      6       False        True         3.0
```

Intermediates:

```
   Index  Value  Condition1  Condition2  where (condition1)  ffill  where (condition2)
0      1      1        True       False                 1.0    1.0                 NaN
1      2      5       False       False                 NaN    1.0                 NaN
2      3      3       False        True                 NaN    1.0                 1.0
3      4      3       False       False                 NaN    1.0                 NaN
4      5      3        True       False                 3.0    3.0                 NaN
5      6      6       False        True                 NaN    3.0                 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df["New Column"] = np.where(df["Condition2"],df['Value'].where(df["Condition1"]).ffill(),
                            None)

print (df)
   Value  Condition1  Condition2 New Column
i                                          
1      1        True       False       None
2      5       False       False       None
3      3       False        True        1.0
4      3       False       False       None
5      3        True       False       None
6      6       False        True        3.0
```

Or:

```
df["New Column"] = np.where(df["Condition2"],df['Value'].where(df["Condition1"]).ffill(),
                            np.nan)

print (df)
   Value  Condition1  Condition2  New Column
i                                           
1      1        True       False         NaN
2      5       False       False         NaN
3      3       False        True         1.0
4      3       False       False         NaN
5      3        True       False         NaN
6      6       False        True         3.0
```